# Trying to find the percentage of black pixels in an image (Python 2)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Black pixels are represented by a B while non black pixels are represented by an N. For each image, calculate the percentage of black pixels to the nearest tenth.

I need the output as **80.0 %** but I got 0.0, what's wrong with my code? Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
line1 = "BBBBBBBBBB"
line2 = "BBNNBBNNBB"
line3 = "BBNNBBNNBB"
line4 = "BBBBBBBBBB"
line5 = "BBBBNNBBBB"
line6 = "BBNBBBBNBB"
line7 = "BBBNNNNBBB"
line8 = "BBBBBBBBBB"

data = ["BBBBBBBBBB", "BBNNBBNNBB", "BBNNBBNNBB", "BBBBBBBBBB", "BBBBNNBBBB", "BBNBBBBNBB", "BBBNNNNBBB", "BBBBBBBBBB"]

def percentBlack(data):
    numB = 0
    numP = 0
    for line in data:
        for pixel in line:
            if pixel == "B":
                numB += 1
            numP += 1
    return round((numB/numP)*100,1)

print(percentBlack(data))
```

Comment: Did you try to cast to floats/doubles before computing the % ? you might be doing an integer division: if the result is between  [0, 1] then you might end up with 0 ! What does debug mode tell you about your variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs fine in Python 3.

I believe your code is written in Python 2 of which the division operator of two int produces an int.  Here is a possible fix.

```
def percentBlack(data):
    numB = 0
    numP = 0
    for line in data:
        for pixel in line:
            if pixel == "B":
                numB += 1
            numP += 1
    return round((numB * 100.0/numP),1)
```

Comment: Yup I need it in Python 2. Great edit! That's what I need. So if I need a % symbol, do I just use this print statement: print(percentBlack(data)), "%"? Any other suggestion?

Comment: That should work, though I usually do print(str(percentBlack(data))+ "%")